# Call a URL from Firestore when using URL Launcher Plugin

Tags: flutter, url, google-cloud-firestore, launcher

I'm using the [url_launcher plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) and want to call the URL from a Firestore collection, rather than hard coding it to the app.

I have tried numerous methods to do this (Streambuilder etc...) but to no avail. In a very simplistic example, using the standard url_launcher example code below, how could this be achieved?

```
void main() {
  runApp(Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchURL,
        child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.dev'; // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL THE URL FROM FIRESTORE
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of having "url" as a constant... pass the URL value as a parameter... done.

Comment: To be honest as simple as I'm sure this is - I guess this is what I have tried, and haven't succeeded with. Is there a quick example you could show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `FutureBuilder`

1. You need to create a future that returns the required `imageurl` from `firestore`. The following code is based on my firestore structure and you might need to change a few things.

   ```
   Future<DocumentSnapshot> geturl(){

    final result = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get();

    return result;
   }
   ```
2. Use `FutureBuilder` to load 'url` from firestore.

   ```
   FutureBuilder(
          future: geturl(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){

              if (snapshot.hasData){
                final String url = snapshot.data.data()['imageUrl'].toString();
                return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async{
                     await launch(url);
                    },
                    child: Text('Firestore url')
                );
              }
              return Text('loading url');
            }
        )
   ```

I have tested this code an it works absolutely fine.